# How to know if dynamic tensor returned by "tf.boolean_mask" is empty or not?

Tags: python, tensorflow

`tf.boolean_mask(tensor, mask) => returns (?, 4)`

How do I check if the returned tensor by `boolean_mask` is empty or not?

Comment: Sorry for deleting my old answer because I didn't see "dynamic tensor".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe we can check whether the size of tensor is equal to 0.

```py
tensor = tf.placeholder(name="tensor",shape=(None,4),dtype=tf.float32)
mask = tf.placeholder(name="mask",shape=(None,4),dtype=tf.bool)
print(tensor.shape)
# (?,4)
after_mask = tf.boolean_mask(tensor, mask)

is_empty = tf.equal(tf.size(after_mask), 0)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    _t = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
    _m_1 = np.random.randint(1,2,size=4).astype(np.bool).reshape(1,4)
    _m_0 = np.random.randint(0,1,size=4).astype(np.bool).reshape(1,4)
    _is_empty_0 = sess.run(is_empty, {tensor: _t, mask: _m_0}) # True
    _is_empty_1 = sess.run(is_empty, {tensor: _t, mask: _m_1}) # False
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to solve this, basically you are trying to identify a null tensor. 
Possible solutions can be:

1. is_empty = tf.equal(tf.size(boolean_tensor), 0). If not empty it will give false
2. Count non zeros number using tf.count_nonzero(boolean_tensor)
3. By simply printing the tensor and checking the vaules